# session_start() causing problems

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am having problems with my code. This is a login/register script I've made by following a tutorial.

The problem I have is that I want the script to echo "logged in" ONLY when the user has entered correct login details, and yet it still echoes "logged in" even if I don't enter any login details. I checked it and if I delete the "session_start()" function, it doesn't do the same thing, but it still doesn't give me access to the session when I want to login.

This is the init.php file, used to initiate the connection with the database and define some other functions:

```
<?php  
session_start();
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
?>
```

This is the connect.php file, used to connect to the database :

```
<?php 
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection issues. This will be solved as soon as possible.';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lr") or die ($connect_error);

mysqli_select_db($con,'lr') or die($connect_error);



mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The general.php file is not important for this question. 
This is the users.php file, where I keep some other functions.

```
function user_id_from_username ($username){
 $username = sanitise($username);
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lr");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $result = $mysqli->query($query);
 while($row=$result->fetch_row()){
     if ($row[1]==$username){ //username == $username 
         return $row[0];//user_id;
     }
 }
 }



 function login ($username, $password){
     $user_id= user_id_from_username($username);
     $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lr");
     $username = sanitise($username);
     $password =md5 ($password);

     $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

     $result = $mysqli -> query($query);

     while ($row =$result -> fetch_row()){
         if($row[1]==$username && $row[2]==$password){
             return TRUE;
         }else {
             return FALSE;
         }

     }

 }
```

This is the file that calls the login function, presented above:

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';




if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username) ===TRUE || empty ($password) === TRUE) {
    $errors[]='You need to enter a username and password!';
} else if (user_exists($username) ===FALSE) {
$errors[]="We can't find that username, have you registered?";
} else if (user_active($username)===FALSE){
$errors[]="You have not activated your account!";
} else{
$login = login($username, $password);
session_start();
if ($login ==false) {
    $errors[] ='That username/password combination is incorrect!';
}else if ($login==true) {
    //set the user session
    $_SESSION['username'] = $login;

    //redirect user to homepage
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

}


if ($errors){
print_r($errors);
}

}
?>
```

And now the index.php file, in which I have the if statement that echoes 'logged in' even if I am not logged in :

```
<?php 

if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo 'not logged_in';

}else {
    echo 'logged in';

}
```

?>

Now I think the problem is located somewhere either in the users.php, login.php or in the index.php file. I presented all of the files so you could get an idea of what I am trying to achieve. This code is spread over so many files because I have functions and interfaces that I have included and I want to be able to reuse the code, so I am using includes.

For you to get a better idea, if my files did not help you enough, I will leave the Youtube link of the tutorial I am following : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUk2e8oqOvI&list=PLE134D877783367C7&index=7#t=6.296979

Thank you,

Waiting for your answer,

Best regards,

Comment: make sure in your each page you start the session where you use the session.

Comment: You have to use session_start() on each page where you are using $_SESSION , put session_start() at start of file

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `$_GET` requests to include the pages, you need to put `session_start()` on top of each file where you are using the `$_SESSION` variable otherwise you can't use the sessions.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Rest of your script
```

I hope this will help you.